# new Spring security 3.2.4 does not store session?

Tags: spring, security

I have a project which need to upgrade from spring security 3.0.5 to 3.2.4. Web.xml is the same, xxx-security-context.xml is almost the same too.

However, when I dump the session from this server, the old one I have:

```
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@42b2cbfe: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@42b2cbfe: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.115.129; SessionId: 7BDDF7F528FD1F2DD5A72AC38F7A70CD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, ROLE_USER
```

The new one 3.2.4 does not have this at all after user login. It seems the session was cleared right after the page loading, which caused the subsequent AJAX call got access is denied.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Post your configuration. There are lots of changes between the versions you mention. Also you note ' xxx-security-context.xml is almost the same too` which means you changed things, what did you change and why.

Comment: oK, it is more clear now. I have some rest call, even after refresh everything is normal. However , I also have some MVC jsp page, when I refresh that, I have lost the security-context and I have to login again.

Comment: It has been resolved, which is due to duplicate authentication filter in web.xml file. Thx!